# Make Symfony2 resources work with SSL

Tags: php, symfony, ssl

I purchased an SSL certificate at OVH in order to have a URL https. They set me the certificate on my website but now, when I access using the https://www.shootandgo.fr , I get errors like

> **:net::ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT**

and the images, the CSS files, and everything else are not found...

I use Symfony 2 and all my resources are on local, in the web directory of Symfony.

OVH has said "*we need to tell Symfony2 to use HTTPS*" but I do not see how... does anyone have a solution? Thank you in advance!

PS: Sorry for my English... I'm French ^^'

Comment: You need to manage htaccess to configure ssl. There are various answer on this topic, just google it.

Comment: your absolute URL's and when you build relative routes, they have to generate it with `https` prefix, not `http` from now. Unless you are doing something special or some sub-requests with curl, etc.

Comment: i already google it and i found something like :    RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA,L] but it doesn't work :(

Comment: @Farside : How prefix them ? Using an htaccess ? If right, why it's not work for me when i use this option ?

Comment: @Christophe, find out my answer below, it has to be done in Symfony, not htaccess really.

Comment: Please, provide more information regarding certificate and server settings/configuration. What kind of certificate is that, with wildcard? do you have CNAME setup for your domain, what ServerAlias is in the `httpd.conf`, etc. Have you tried to access your domain, without symfony installed there, is it framework bug at all, or just server settings thing and wrong domain/certificate configuration?

Comment: I checked certificates via `openssl s_client -servername shootandgo.fr -connect 46.105.174.39:443 -state` , `openssl s_client -servername benzing.cc -connect 46.105.174.39:443 -state` , `openssl s_client -servername sosmediterranee.org -connect 46.105.174.39:443 -state`. Your domain can't be reached via ssl (w/o issues): `SSL3 alert read:fatal:unrecognized name`, but another two domains can be accessed w/o any problems. If this is dedicated server or vps, it's not hoster's issue, call to your admin :)

Comment: @Wizard : I had asked to my hoster (it'es a mutualized server so i don't have any access) and there are any problems for them. I had put simple files to my server and indeed there is no problems, so my problem came to Symfony :(

Comment: @Christophe , I see you resolved the question :) .. what kind of problem was there? a hoster's issue or symfony-based application ?

Comment: @Wizard, hi :) Yes the question was resolved yesterday, i've just un-deploy and deploy again the project...In the same time i've called the hoster to say "hey there is a problem", but they told me that was not their fault sooo i don't know if it was right or wrong and if they have done something... ^^'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well i have upload again my website on the server, and everything is normal now...I don't know why there was a problem on it las tt

Answer (score 1):

To make symfony2 work with HTTPS, you need to reference these sections in their manual:

1. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/scheme.html
2. http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/force_https.html

More information could be found by the links above, but generally speaking everything is defined in app configs:

```
secure:
    path:     /secure
    defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Main:secure }
    schemes:  [https]
```

and this:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
# ...

access_control:
    - { path: ^/secure, roles: ROLE_ADMIN, requires_channel: https }
```

---

The said above was related to Symfony2 thing, which you was asking about.

But my guess is, that this error `ERR_SSL_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT` belongs to the wrong server/certificate setup, not to specific framework you are using. You'd need to elaborate more, and to provide additional information to figure this out.

Comment: hum, i've tried this add scheme on my route using https, add requires channel on the access_control but nothing change.... -_-

Comment: @Christophe, but are you sure the error is connected to you symfony2 settings? Because it sounds to me, that something is wrong with your domain/subdomain configuration on Apache, rather than with Symfony2. Can you may be, edit you question and post additional details?

Comment: well i had asked OVH and they said me "you have to check Symfony to tell it that you are using https and not http"...I can't check the configuration of Apache because i am on a mutualized server...

Comment: @Christophe, you may try to un-deploy symfony from there, and to make sure your certificate works at all with any dummy content (CSS, HTML-page) for you domain/subdomain. Because I have no clue who's OVH and whether they did the setup and configuration right.

Comment: oh yes sorry, OVH is the first european web hoster. I will try what you just said and be right back to give an answer